# Git get old submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am working on a GIT repository (called `A` here). It includes a submodule (called `B` here). When clone a new copy of `A` by

```
git clone --recursive <repository url for A>
```

`A` and `B` are cloned, but the version of `B` is out-of-date! No matter how I updated it by

```
git submodule update
```

When I cloned only `B`, it is up-to-date.

What is wrong? My git version is `git version 1.7.7.5 (Apple Git-26)`, and my repository is on `bitbucket`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While inside A, `cd` to dir where B is.

```
cd path/to/B/inside/A
```

Now you can `checkout` any commit that you want to have in A.

```
git checkout <branch or commit>
```

(You may need to `fetch` / `pull` the latest changes before this `checkout`.)

Now go back to the root dir of A, and commit the change.

```
cd -
git add path/to/B/inside/A
git commit -m "Update submodule B pointer."
```

From now on, `git clone` or `git submodule update` will `checkout` that commit.

Note that B is independent of A, so B can have any state in terms of branches, but as a submodule of A, it will point to the  commit that A wants. This allows independent development of the two repos.

Comment: How do I keep B inside A the newest version?

Comment: You mean "How do I keep newest version of B inside A"? You can not have that automatically, afaik. Whenever you need B to point to a new commit, you will have to do that manually. That is, update the commit inside the dir, and then `add` and `commit` that change in A.

Comment: Consider a case where B is a third party library you are using inside your project A. Its all working nicely, but someone makes a change in B that breaks how it integrates with your project. If that is automatically changed in your project A, then suddenly your A will start breaking, without you doing anything. Then you would end up looking for a working commit in B, and would try to keep to that commit. To prevent all this, if you add any submodule to A, then YOU decide what commit (version) of the code you like to use in A. And if you want to change, you have to do that explicitly.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds reasonable!